# How to add content to a div based on the data-attr value of it

Tags: jquery

I have got two div's with same class name as TreeMenuChild  but the identification is based on the data-attr values  of it

```
<div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-a" aria-hidden="false">
        <div class="TreeMenuChild" data-attr="one" data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
             <h3><a href="#">200 ML</a></h3>

            <div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-a" aria-hidden="false"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="TreeMenuChild" data-attr="two" data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
             <h3><a href="#">300 Milli liters</a></h3>

            <div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-a ui-collapsible-content-collapsed" aria-hidden="true"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have got two div's as shown below

```
var firstdivcontent = '<div id="footer">Add this to First </div>';
var seconddivcontent = '<div id="footer">Add this to Second </div>';
```

I am trying to add

firstdivcontent to the TreeMenuChild which has got data-attr="one" and
seconddivcontent to the TreeMenuChild which has got data-attr="two"

I was trying this way , but could you please let me know why the div is being added to both the above div of TreeMenuChild

```
$(document).on("click", "#firstbtn", function () {
   if ($('#datacontainer').find('.TreeMenuChild').attr('data-attr') == 'one') {
        $(".TreeMenuChild .ui-collapsible-content").append(firstdivcontent).trigger("create");
    }
});


$(document).on("click", "#secondbtnbtn", function () {
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u8fjv78s/7/

Could you please let me know how to do this ??

Comment: a quick look through selectors section of jQuery API would show you how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not to keep it simple by using the proper selector `.TreeMenuChild[data-attr=one]`

```
$(document).on("click", "#firstbtn", function () {

        $(".TreeMenuChild[data-attr=one]").append(firstdivcontent).trigger("create");

});
```

Answer (score 1):

To select any html elements based on  their attributes you can use the syntax [attribute='value'].

For a div like so:

```
<div data-prop="one"></div>
```

you could write:

```
$("div[data-prop='one']").html("html");
```

and you would see html in the contents of the div.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x5f5x1nx/

Answer (score 1):

Within jQuery to retrieve the `dataset` property on elements, you would need to use [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) on the `dataset` name rather than `attr` function which you are using.

```
$(document).on("click", "#firstbtn", function () {

   if ($('#datacontainer').find('.TreeMenuChild').data('attr') == 'one') {
        // do whatever
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks , but still the first content is  being added to the two div's

Comment: I guess this line is creating problem  $(".TreeMenuChild .ui-collapsible-content").append(firstdivcontent).trigger("create"); , is it possible to that particular div only ??